# Docker compose ecs fargate attach custom security group to load balancer

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I want to attach a custom security group to the load balancer (To accept traffic from cloud front) for my ecs deployment from docker

Below is my docker-compose.yml file and I need to attach security group `sg-0828b05baf4899773` to the load balancer that gets created by cloudformation. Alternativly I would be open to a way to use cloudfront as part of docker-compose where the cloudfront distribution is created as part of cloudformation.

```
services:
  application:
    image: 000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/org/pos:latest
    platform: linux/amd64
    env_file: .env.${ENV}
    build:
      context: "."
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
    networks:
      - mail
      - app_network
  postfix:
    image: 000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/org/postfix:latest
    platform: linux/amd64
    build:
      context: "postfix"
    container_name: postfix
    networks:
      - mail
      - app_network
    hostname: postfix
    restart: always
networks:
  app_network:
      name: tcetra_network
  mail:
    name: postfix-mail
x-aws-cloudformation:
  Resources:
    ApplicationTCP80Listener:
      Properties:
        Certificates:
          - CertificateArn: "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:088048903606:certificate/d7a330ce-77d6-4753-bcf0-913f8ac0cee3"
        Protocol: HTTPS
        Port: 443
    ApplicationTCP80TargetGroup:
      Properties:
        HealthCheckPath: /health.html
        Matcher:
          HttpCode: 200-499
```

Answer (score 0):

The docker-compose ECS support generates a CloudFormation template from your docker-compose.yaml file. Per [the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/#tuning-the-cloudformation-template), You can create CloudFormation overlays in the docker-compose file via `x-aws-cloudformation`.

You are already doing this in your docker-compose file to specify custom SSL certificate, and a custom health check.

To customize other aspects of the generated CloudFormation template, you should first run `docker compose convert` to generate a CloudFormation stack file from your Compose file. You can then view that file to find the security group resource, and then include the needed changes for that resource in your docker-compose.yaml file.

Comment: Got it, I think that helps me a lot!